# <?=form_open(''); ?> call to undefined function

Tags: codeigniter-form-helper

I have this pblm, 
i have been trying to create master view layout using jquery & 
codeigniter.
What i was trying to do is simple, i have following files

template.php &
content.php

template.php have a

```
             <div id="container">
```

and i want to load one of my div's from content.php based on the link clicked. everything gets loaded into  #container div except the form_open tag returns error. i have configured it in autoload & also tried to load it in controller, but both are not working

```
   <div id="container">
        <h2>Create New User</h2>
        <?=form_open('form/createuser'); ?>
    .
    .
        <?=form_close(); ?>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@RahulArackal, You can please add below code in the beginning of your controller code.

`$this->load->helper('form');`

Also u can do other thing like auto load this helper file in autoload.php.

`$autoload['helper'] = array('form');`

Also you should apply echo before the form_open().

Let me know if still any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php echo form_open('form/createuser'); ?>
   .
   .
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```